# Android : change the background color of click on same button

Tags: android

I have one TextView in my application and want to change the Background color of the same TextView .When i click 1st time it would be red , click on same 2nd time it would be green and 3rd time click it would be blue color background by problematically.

```
 textType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textRNG);
        textType.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Drawable d = textType.getBackground();
                Log.e("textType "," click !!! ");

                if(d.getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red_circle_shape).getConstantState())
                {
                    textType.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_circle_shape);
                }
                if(d.getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green_circle_shape).getConstantState())
                {
                    textType.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_circle_shape);
                }
                if(d.getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue_circle_shape).getConstantState())
                {
                    textType.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_circle_shape);
                }


            }
        });
```

This cod is not working.Thanks to appropriate.

Comment: introduce a counting veriable and increment it on each click. then change the color according to the counting value

Comment: Thanks all code are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code,

```
textType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textRNG);
    textType.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        private int mCounter = 0;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (mCounter == 0)
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_circle_shape);
            else
               if (mCounter == 1)
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_circle_shape);
            else
               v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_circle_shape);

            mCounter++;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a global variable `x` initialize it with `0`. Then code like this:

```
textType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textRNG); 
        textType.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v)
            { 
            if(x<4)
            {
            x= x+1;
            }
            else{
            x = 1;
            }

            if(x==1)
            {
            // red color
            }
            else if(x==2)
            {
            // blue color
            }
            else if(x==3)
            {
            // green color
            }


            } 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

- Define a global Variable int type.
- Inside your onClick(), increment the int Variable

  - use switch or if statement to change the color when the variable increases e.g.

  If(variable == 1)
  // change color to Blue 
  else if (variable == 2)
  // change color to Yellow

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

TextView textType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textRNG);

```
    textType.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(current)
            {
                case 1:
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
                current = 2;
                break;
                case 2:
                    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0000ff"));
                    current = 3;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
                    current = 1;
                    break;
                   default:
                       break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Use the following code to Change the Color. Paste these lines inside your textView Onclick. Variable count is a global variable.

```
    if (count == 0)
        txtView.setTextColor(colorcode1);
    else if (count == 1)
        txtView.setTextColor(colorcode2);
    else
        txtView.setTextColor(colorcode3);
    count++;
    if (count > 2)
        count = 0;
```